# Push To view controller from View is not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to push to a view controller from a view class using tap gesture action. All the below lines are executed, but the control not pushing to respective view controller. I need to push to that view controller, but not to set the controller as root view,because i need to navigate back to some other navigated view controller. Any one please help me.

```
let webViewController = R2WebViewViewController()
currentWindow.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: from where u r calling this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
currentWindow.rootViewController?.navigationController?
```

Your problem is that your `rootViewController` is probably an `UINavigationController` already, so you should do:

```
let webViewController = R2WebViewViewController()
(currentWindow.rootViewController as? UINavigationController).pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Dude

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(currentWindow?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController).pushViewController(webViewController, animated: true)
```

Your root must be navVC

Comment: I tried this code.. But i got some error message like "Value of type UIViewcontroller has no member PushViewController" like that

Comment: anytime sir, happy to help :)